# Button to True the Checkbox

Tags: excel, database, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a button that in the Onclick event an checkbox gets tick(True) in Google Sheets

Expecting an Onclick event that will check the checkbox

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Excel and Google Sheets are two very different programs, please remove the irrelevant one from the tags.

Comment: A code that runs on opening the sheet to set the values to false.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Script that runs upon selecting an image (button). To do this you will need to open up the Apps Script section (under Extensions) and add this code to the code.gs:

```
function ticker() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = 'A1'; //change to the cell you wish to toggle true
  sheet.getRange(range).setValue('true');
}
```

Then in sheets add an image and assign the image (by selecting the 3 dots in the upper right corner) to the script "ticker". This will require you to trust the source of the code on first run. Upon clicking the button the cell will be changed to true resulting in the checkbox to be checked. If you need a range of cells to be toggled use the following:

```
function ticker() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeList = ['A1:A5','C1:C5']; //change to the cells you wish to toggle true
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue('true');
}
```

[image]